# Roblox animation toolanim and Slash meaning

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

How do the literal strings "toolanim" and "Slash" reference the Tool's animation?

I am just trying to understand how these strings are referenced.

```
local function Attack ()            
    local anim = Instance.new("StringValue")
    anim.Name = "toolanim"
    anim.Value = "Slash"
    anim.Parent = script.Parent 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tool) the default character script will listen for a StringValue with Name toolanim.

You create this value and give it a parent. Setting the Parent property will make it a child of that parent. That's when the parent gets to know that there is a StringValue with that particular Name and it will responde to it by playing the animation.
That StringValue is then most likely destroyed and the script will wait for another instance to respond to.

Here's a very mimimum implementation in Lua:

```
local parent = setmetatable({}, {__newindex = function (t,k,v)
 
  if k == "Child" and v.Name == "toolanim" then
    print("parent: Hey someone gave me a child named toolanim!")
    print("parent: let's see what I need to do!")
    if v.Value == "Slash" then
      print("Slash!!!! <- fancy animation")
    end
  end
end})

local stringValue = setmetatable({},{__newindex = function (t,k,v)
  if k == "Parent" then
  print("stringValue: Someone gave me a Parent! Hey parent, I'm your child now!")
    rawset(t, "Parent", v)
    v.Child = t
  else
     rawset(t, k, v)
  end

end})

stringValue.Name = "toolanim"
stringValue.Value = "Slash"
stringValue.Parent = parent
```

This creates some parent object that if it gets a child will run an "animation" if the child has the right properties.

The other object will set itself as the parent's child when it gets a parent which triggers the whole thing.

This is implemented using Lua's __newindex metamethod. Please refer to the Lua reference [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4) if this is not clear.